# transform list elements based on the string type (style)

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list like below,

```
['Message-ID: <5525962.1075855679785.JavaMail.evans@thyme>\r\n',
'Date: Wed, 13 Dec 2000 07:04:00 -0800 (PST)\r\n',
'From: phillip.allen@enron.com\r\n',
'To: christi.nicolay@enron.com, james.steffes@enron.com, jeff.dasovich@enron.com, \r\n',
'\tjoe.hartsoe@enron.com, mary.hain@enron.com, pallen@enron.com,\r\n',
'\tpkaufma@enron.com, richard.sanders@enron.com, \r\n',
'\trichard.shapiro@enron.com, stephanie.miller@enron.com, \r\n',
'\tsteven.kean@enron.com, susan.mara@enron.com, \r\n',
'\trebecca.cantrell@enron.com\r\n',
'Subject: \r\n',
'Mime-Version: 1.0\r\n']
```

In that `To` attribute contains only 3 e-mail ids, followed by that elements some elements starts with `\t`. Actually those `\t` list elements continuation of `To` attribute. My objective is I want to merge all the missing elements from the `To` attribute.

So far I used this below code to solve my problem.

```
l=['Message-ID: <5525962.1075855679785.JavaMail.evans@thyme>\r\n',
'Date: Wed, 13 Dec 2000 07:04:00 -0800 (PST)\r\n',
'From: phillip.allen@enron.com\r\n',
'To: christi.nicolay@enron.com, james.steffes@enron.com, jeff.dasovich@enron.com, \r\n',
'\tjoe.hartsoe@enron.com, mary.hain@enron.com, pallen@enron.com,\r\n',
'\tpkaufma@enron.com, richard.sanders@enron.com, \r\n',
'\trichard.shapiro@enron.com, stephanie.miller@enron.com, \r\n',
'\tsteven.kean@enron.com, susan.mara@enron.com, \r\n',
'\trebecca.cantrell@enron.com\r\n',
'Subject: \r\n',
'Mime-Version: 1.0\r\n']
act= [ele.rstrip('\r\n') for ele in l if ele.startswith('To: ')]
rem=[ele.lstrip('\t').rstrip('\r\n') for ele in l if ele.startswith('\t')]
act.extend(rem)
act=[''.join(act)]

l=[ele for ele in l if not ele.startswith('To: ') and not ele.startswith('\t')]
l.extend(act)
print l
```

Output:

```
['Message-ID: <5525962.1075855679785.JavaMail.evans@thyme>\r\n',
'Date: Wed, 13 Dec 2000 07:04:00 -0800 (PST)\r\n',
'From: phillip.allen@enron.com\r\n',
'Subject: \r\n',
'Mime-Version: 1.0\r\n',
'To: christi.nicolay@enron.com, james.steffes@enron.com, jeff.dasovich@enron.com, joe.hartsoe@enron.com, mary.hain@enron.com, pallen@enron.com,pkaufma@enron.com, richard.sanders@enron.com, richard.shapiro@enron.com, stephanie.miller@enron.com, steven.kean@enron.com, susan.mara@enron.com, rebecca.cantrell@enron.com']
```

I think I have made more complexity to my code.

Is there any simple way or any other better way to approach this problem?
or where can I improve my code efficiency?

any efforts would be really appreciable.,

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that the '\r','\t' and '\n' characters are redundant and  should be removed.
Though I don't know what intentions you have, may I proposed to
convert this into a dictionary for easier access in the future.

```
m_list = ['Message-ID: <5525962.1075855679785.JavaMail.evans@thyme>\r\n',
'Date: Wed, 13 Dec 2000 07:04:00 -0800 (PST)\r\n',
'From: phillip.allen@enron.com\r\n',
'To: christi.nicolay@enron.com, james.steffes@enron.com, jeff.dasovich@enron.com, \r\n',
'\tjoe.hartsoe@enron.com, mary.hain@enron.com, pallen@enron.com,\r\n',
'\tpkaufma@enron.com, richard.sanders@enron.com, \r\n',
'\trichard.shapiro@enron.com, stephanie.miller@enron.com, \r\n',
'\tsteven.kean@enron.com, susan.mara@enron.com, \r\n',
'\trebecca.cantrell@enron.com\r\n',
'Subject: \r\n',
'Mime-Version: 1.0\r\n']

m_dict = {}

for m in m_list:
    m = m.split(':', maxsplit=1)    
    if len(m) > 1:
        key, value = m[0], m[1]
        m_dict[key] = value.strip() 
    else:
        m_dict['To'] = m_dict['To'] + ' ' + m[0].strip()

print(m_dict)
```

Output:
{`'Message-ID': '<5525962.1075855679785.JavaMail.evans@thyme>', 'Date': 'Wed, 13 Dec 2000 07:04:00 -0800 (PST)', 'From': 'phillip.allen@enron.com', 'To': 'christi.nicolay@enron.com, james.steffes@enron.com, jeff.dasovich@enron.com, joe.hartsoe@enron.com, mary.hain@enron.com, pallen@enron.com, pkaufma@enron.com, richard.sanders@enron.com, richard.shapiro@enron.com, stephanie.miller@enron.com, steven.kean@enron.com, susan.mara@enron.com, rebecca.cantrell@enron.com', 'Subject': '', 'Mime-Version': '1.0'}`

Answer (score 2):

You are parsing email message, it is quite tricky as there are many corner case. You should have a look at python [email module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/email.html) in order to avoid many pitfalls.

```
import email

headers = ['Message-ID: <5525962.1075855679785.JavaMail.evans@thyme>\r\n',
  'Date: Wed, 13 Dec 2000 07:04:00 -0800 (PST)\r\n',
  'From: phillip.allen@enron.com\r\n',
  'To: christi.nicolay@enron.com, james.steffes@enron.com, jeff.dasovich@enron.com, \r\n',
  '\tjoe.hartsoe@enron.com, mary.hain@enron.com, pallen@enron.com,\r\n',
  '\tpkaufma@enron.com, richard.sanders@enron.com, \r\n',
  '\trichard.shapiro@enron.com, stephanie.miller@enron.com, \r\n',
  '\tsteven.kean@enron.com, susan.mara@enron.com, \r\n',
  '\trebecca.cantrell@enron.com\r\n',
  'Subject: \r\n',
  'Mime-Version: 1.0\r\n']

mail = email.message_from_string("".join(headers)+"\r\n"+"foo body") # rebuild mail message and parse

for to in email.utils.getaddresses(mail.get_all("to")):
    print(to[1])
```

produce

```
christi.nicolay@enron.com
james.steffes@enron.com
jeff.dasovich@enron.com
joe.hartsoe@enron.com
mary.hain@enron.com
pallen@enron.com
pkaufma@enron.com
richard.sanders@enron.com
richard.shapiro@enron.com
stephanie.miller@enron.com
steven.kean@enron.com
susan.mara@enron.com
rebecca.cantrell@enron.com
```

Comment: It's really cool, I'm unaware of this, thanks for the answer :-)

Comment: @MohamedThasinah you're wellcome. Maybe you should add "email" tag to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Thought this will be a much simpler and easy to understand solution for your given problem-

```
  arr=['Message-ID: <5525962.1075855679785.JavaMail.evans@thyme>\r\n',
'Date: Wed, 13 Dec 2000 07:04:00 -0800 (PST)\r\n',
'From: phillip.allen@enron.com\r\n',
'To: christi.nicolay@enron.com, james.steffes@enron.com, jeff.dasovich@enron.com, \r\n',
'\tjoe.hartsoe@enron.com, mary.hain@enron.com, pallen@enron.com,\r\n',
'\tpkaufma@enron.com, richard.sanders@enron.com, \r\n',
'\trichard.shapiro@enron.com, stephanie.miller@enron.com, \r\n',
'\tsteven.kean@enron.com, susan.mara@enron.com, \r\n',
'\trebecca.cantrell@enron.com\r\n',
'Subject: \r\n',
'Mime-Version: 1.0\r\n']

reqd_array=[]
k=""

for i in arr:
    if ':' in i:
        reqd_array.append(i.strip())
    else:
        k=k+i.strip()
for i,j in enumerate(reqd_array):
    if j.startswith("To:"):
        reqd_array[i]=reqd_array[i]+k
        break
print(reqd_array)
```